# Python web scraper by using Selenium and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-multithreading

I have the following function.It takes a link as an argument, and gives me the data I need at the end (base_list)

```
def extract_BS(link):

    base_list = []

    try:

        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.get(link)                   
        print('Processing..' + link)

        respData = browser.page_source
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(respData, 'html.parser')
        browser.quit()
        shipping_options = soup.find("div", class_ = "modal_shipping_con").find_all("input", class_="inputChangePrice")
        base_list.append(shipping_options)

    except Exception as e:
        print(urls)
        print('Exception:',e)
        pass

    return base_list
```

However, my list of urls is around 1000, so it takes too long to do them individually. I found [this blog](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/how-to-speed-up-your-python-web-scraper-by-using-multiprocessing-f2f4ef838686) on multiprocessing, which I am trying to tweak

My additional code to use the multithreading is as follows

```
with Pool(4) as p:
    records = p.map(extract_BS,urls)

p.terminate()
p.join()
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error.

```
MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result:
Reason: 'RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded in       comparison',)'
```

When I run the script, 4 windows pop open, and the webscraper does its thing, but it seems like the problem lies with 'records = p.map(extract_BS,urls)'. My function outputs a list, which I want to store in 'results', but for some reason this is not working.

Any advice/help/observations much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Figured out what was wrong. It has something to do with the beautiful soup library - there is a problem extracting html simultaneously that the library didn't cover. I removed the bs aspects of the script, and it worked. Now I save the output, and then use beautiful outside the function to parse

Answer (score 0):

You need to place

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

before with Pool(4) as p to prevent to create a pool in each pool which causes the recursion error.

Comment: I adjusted the last part of the code to the below, but I got the same error:                                                                                                  if __name__ == "__main__":
        with Pool(4) as p:
            records = p.map(extract_BS,urls)
        p.terminate()
        p.join()